# Identifying duplicates and choosing which duplicate row to drop

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need help trying to clean up my dataset. Within a set of unique ID's, there are duplicate Title/Artist Names, and of those duplicates, there is a line that doesn't contain any value/text for the Album column.

What I want to do first is identify duplicates with in that subset of Mix IDs, then drop the row that doesn't have any value/text in the Album column.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, and any help would be awesome!

DF:

[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Partial dataframe 
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Mix_id':[1234567, 1234567, 1234567, 1234567, 1234567],
                   'Title':['Hello its me', 'Music', 'Evolve', 'Evolve', 'Signs'],
                   'Artist':['Martin', 'Ones and Twos', 'Julian', 'Julian', 'Julian'],
                   'Album':["", "", "", "Evolve", ""]})
```

The initial dataframe:

[image]

```
df = df.groupby(['Mix_id', 'Title', 'Artist'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x[x.Album.str.len() == x.Album.str.len().max()])
df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True, inplace=True)
df.sort_index()
```

The output:

[image]